# how to extract array variables from xml sheet?

Tags: mysql, xml, arrays, extract

I hope someone can help me. I need to extract certain details ("Full Name and Surname", "Email", "Contact Number) from a MySQL DB but can't figure out how to do this. The application in question, "Grunion Contact Form" for Wordpress saves the data in the DB, in an array, as follows:

```
Array
(
    [Full Name and Surname:] =&gt; Sharon Somerset
    [Email] =&gt; sharon@x.x.x
    [Contact Number:] =&gt; 08xxxxxx
    [Alternative Number] =&gt; 011xxxxxx
    [Please list convenient time to be contacted] =&gt; 
    [Medical Aid Quote] =&gt; Yes
    [Insurance Quote] =&gt; 
    [Policy Update] =&gt; 
    [Friend's Name and Surname:] =&gt; 
    [Friend's Contact Number:] =&gt; 
    [How did you find us?] =&gt; Google
)
```

Each entry is in it's own database row, inside "longtext" field.

How can I easily extract "Full Name and Surname", "Email", "Contact Number" data from a few thousands rows like this, and re-save in a simple table or CSV file to import into something like phplist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started - its simple regular expression matching on the text field. This will take a while to run through - but it does what you need.

```
<?php
$string = "Array
(
    [Full Name and Surname:] => Sharon Somerset
    [Email] => sharon@x.x.x
    [Contact Number:] => 08xxxxxx
    [Alternative Number] => 011xxxxxx
    [Please list convenient time to be contacted] => 
    [Medical Aid Quote] => Yes
    [Insurance Quote] => 
    [Policy Update] => 
    [Friend's Name and Surname:] => 
    [Friend's Contact Number:] => 
    [How did you find us?] => Google
)";


$string = preg_replace("/Array\n\(\n/","",$string);
//remove first line

$string = preg_replace("/\)$/","",$string);
//remove last line

$lines = explode("\n",$string);
//split on new lines
print_r($lines);

foreach($lines as $l)
{
        preg_match("/\[(.+)\] => (.*)$/",$l,$matches);
        //$matches[1] will contain the label
        //$matches[2] will contain the value
        print_r($matches);

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanx Geek Num 88.

Sorry, I think my initial question wasn't accurate enough. I have a file with a few thousand (I can't figure out how many due to how Excel displays it) of those lines, with different client's details and I need to extract just the client's contact details.

Comment: OK - I wanted to get you started in the right direction and not do all the work for you. With the code above you should be able to parse all the information from any source and populate another file with that data.